# Amazon RDS differential restore

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it possible to do something like this in Amazon RDS:

1. Do a Full restore of a database and have it online immediately
2. Perform a differential restore of the db after it becomes online

So, from the official AWS docs, the db needs to be in RESTORE state before you can do a differential restore. Is there a way to make a db enter the RESTORE state after it becomes online upon successful full restore?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No, you can't.

This isn't an RDS specific problem - this is built into the SQL engine. If you want to restore a differential you first need to restore the corresponding FULL backup using RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY.

You can see in the image below of the SSMS restore window that the Differential's *Full LSN* value matches the Full backup's *Checkpoint LSN* and that's a dependency that you lose when you recover a database before applying the differential.
[image]

When a database is restored with recovery it goes through Redo and Undo processes to bring the database into a transactionally consistent state. If the database has already come online WITH RECOVERY, then the database would not longer be transactionally consistent with the changes represented in the differential backup. If you want to apply a differential, you'd need to do a clean RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY and apply the differential before you recover the database.

This article might be a good read to understand what happens in a RECOVERY vs a NORECOVERY scenario - https://www.sqlmvp.org/restore-database-with-norecovery/